# How can I increase the number of columns (characters on each line) of Tex compilation log (text output)?

Tags: compiling, logging

The question is similar, but the answer here is more general.
The log output width is limited to 80 characters.
For example, this output:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code
.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.t
ex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldp
gfsupp_loader.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex
)
```

could be:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run

```
 kpsewhich --all texmf.cnf
```

to see where your config files are located. Then insert into
the local one for example:

```
error_line = 120
half_error_line = 70
max_print_line = 120
```

Comment: But that is not the local one, right? There must be something like `/usr/local/share/texmf/`

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong filename, in my system: `sudo pico /etc/texmf/texmf.d/00debian.cnf; sudo update-texmf`.